# How to write braces inside \sqrt[ in here ]{sth}?

Tags: brackets, braces, sqrt

This is what I want to write:

[image]

Apparently, the following doesn't work

`\sqrt[ \sqrt[\log n]{n} ]{x}`

The error is that the argument of `\sqrt` has an extra `}`. This seems like a bug to me. Is there a way to write this symbol?

Comment: It should be `\sqrt[{\sqrt[\log n]{n}}]{x}`, but are you sure you want that monster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the second `\sqrt` into `{...}`.

*Edit:* I've added a possible alternative to the monster.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\begin{document} 
    \[ 
    \sqrt[{\sqrt[\log n]{n}}]{x} 
    \]
I prefer this possibile alternative:
    \[
    {x}^{{\bigl[{n}^{{(\log n)}^{-1}}\bigr]^{-1}}}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I know of this alternative, but i wanted to specifically emphasize the root sign. Your original answer is perfectly fine. This one is a welcome addition of course.

Comment: @RestlessC0bra There's a reason for creating the monster, then, hahaha!